# Additional Detail from IPEDS Data Source

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, education

I have used NCES IPEDS data in the past, but this recent release seems to have instituted a change. In looking at the NCES college navigator site for a particular institution, I notice that they now break out satellite campuses with a longer `UNITID` code (instead of a separate code as in years past), such as found here: http://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=150987

However, when I download the `HD2012.csv` table from http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/DataFiles.aspx I can not find those satellite campus codes.

Does anyone know from where I can download the data for those particular institutions?

Answer (score 1):

The entry for IPEDS on data.gov (https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/integrated-postsecondary-education-data-system-ipeds-data-center) provides a point of contact. Recommend emailing the dataset POC directly.

Answer (score 0):

Historically since 1986, ED had a handful of campuses that only reported Institutional characteristics data, and data for all other surveys were reported with the parent campus.  In 2003, ED termed these institutions as perfect children campuses.  ED assigned them an 8 digit IPEDS ID and would ask the parent campus to list the campuses/locations that would be listed on College navigator only (http://www.collegenavigator.gov/).  The parent campus provides name and address and the award levels offered by the institution and the tuition and fees.  They do not supply any other information, so in 2003 it was determined these campuses would be shown on College Navigator only and not be part of the IPEDS Data Center.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It sounds logical, and I know institutions with multiple locations did not always report data separately for each location. However, I know you said they did that in 2003, but the affect only seems to have occurred in (and after) the 2011 release. Is that just part of their delay in data release? Also, do you have any idea why they would choose not to release that raw data as part of the directory information?